Installing Windows Server 2022 on Hyper-V
Creating a new VM on my Windows Server 2019 machine. The new VM will be a Gen 2 Windows Server 2022 installation.
I am using the latest image ISO from Admin 365 account. Brand new VM and brand new ISO. On installation it gets to "Getting Files ready for Installation" and then throws and error at around 49%.
Error

Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or
missing. Make sure all files required for installation are available,
and restart the installation.
Error code: 0x80070570

UPDATE: Installing on a Gen 1 by mounting the same ISO burned to a DVD and install it directly from the DVD and it installed correctly.
Why won't the Gen 2 install with the ISO if the burned DVD from the same ISO works?

@TomTom I don't know what to fix? Its an ISO. Its direct from Microsoft. What's to fix?

It's probably just a corrupted ISO. Re-download it.

@Massimo I just re-downloaded the ISO from Microsoft. Get the same error with this one as I had with the original one from February.

Try it with the ISO from the evaluation site for comparison. https://info.microsoft.com/ww-landing-windows-server-2022.html

Redownloading may just hit the cache. Check CRC. There are checksums for a reasons.
